# App crashes automatically when I completed the cropping image without any error logs. I used expo-image-picker

Tags: react-native, expo

the app crashes and closed automatically without any error logs.

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync()({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      // aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
```

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? We are seeing the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

yes I saw this bug lately, it seems shown in bar flow, by the way, Its work with me after I cancel cropping by delete
`allowsEditing: true`

- Or you can go back to pick image expo module documentation and follow linking module manually.
  https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-image-picker
- Or just copy this activity to your manifest file

`<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity" android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"> </activity>`

good luck

Comment: This is not the answer, please get reputation and make comments.